# How to convert an image from YCRCB to RGB using PIL library?

Tags: color-space, video-compression

I want to convert an image "from YCRCB" to "RGB" using PIL library

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a tweak

```
    if img.mode != 'RGB':

       img = img.convert('RGB')
```

The image you are trying to convert should be opened using PIL library